# No more appearance menu

Tags: 13.04

Just updated my machine (it runs Ubuntu 12.10), but now it says I run 13.04 (what) and I can no longer access the Appearance menu in System Settings.  What's going on?

Comment: 13.04 isn't released yet.  In order to upgrade to an unfinished development version you would have had to specifically alter your sources.list file and/or run a special command such as `update-manager -d`.  Perhaps you could give more information about how you upgraded.  What did you do?

Comment: @neon_overload I just ran 'sudo apt-get update' like I do everyday, but it prompted me to restart, and when I did, my problems began.

Comment: What makes you think you're running 13.04?

Comment: @neon_overload When I go to settings>details, it says I am.  http://imgur.com/Q5RWAgj

Comment: AFAIK, you would have had to specifically alter your sources.list file and/or run a special command such as `update-manager -d` to do that.  Maybe pasting your sources.list file (as a pastebin, perhaps) might show us some clues?

Comment: @neon_overload Here you are http://pastebin.com/XJ017RKN

Comment: All your sources still point to Quantal, which is 12.10, so this is evidence (but not proof) that thankfully you *haven't* updated to 13.04.  The about page might be some sort of bug?  I'm sorry that I don't think I can help you further, but at least this should have given people a bit more info.

Comment: @neon_overload Thanks, I'll check around more, see if anyone else is having this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the Appearance menu in System Settings by installing gnome-control-center-unity

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center-unity
```

Comment: Had exactly the same issue after upgrading to 13.04 today using the update-manager -d , and installing gnome-control-center-unity got the appearence utility back!